# Correct file in production mode Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my web site, i found a mistake inside a text on my html (langage => language)

I change directly here /app/views/ with vi text editor but when I reload my page (after navigator history cleanning). The mistake is still here

There is a kind of step to take in account the modification?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In Production you normally have to restart the server for changes to take place

Comment: Also, making quick fixes in production like this is a bad practice.

Comment: It works. thanks. For other people : [CODE]service apache2 restart[/CODE]. for marek : here it's juts add a "u"

Comment: I am still wondering how the buggy code went up to production without testing